# Having difficulty solving ODE: $y' = \frac{1}{2} a y^2 + b y - 1$ with $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying for an exam about ODEs and I am struggling with one of the past exam questions. The past exam shows one exercise which asks us to solve:
$$y' = \frac{1}{2} a y^2 + b y - 1$$with $y(0)=0$

The solution is given as
$$y(x) = \frac{2 \left( e^{\Gamma x} - 1 \right)}{(b + \Gamma)(e^{\Gamma x} - 1) + 2\Gamma},$$ with $\Gamma = \sqrt{b^2 + 2a}$

I have tried numerous approaches, among other Bernoulli differential equations and variable separable methods. I keep on getting stuck on solving the integral that I encounter, and if I am able to solve it it looks nowhere near the solution as provided by the professor. If someone could show me the steps I would be very thankfull! I have invested too many hours of my time on this question now and giving up is no more option!

Comment: This is a variable seperable equation. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: What in the answers to your previous question to this same problem did you not understand?

Comment: @LutzL This is indeed a duplicate as I felt that the other topic got a little lost in the many questions posted every day. Altough the answers were helpful, I was not able to find a satisfying solution which actually matched the exact solution of the professor...

Comment: Then I recommend you ask your professor if you need the solution to match.

Comment: You can use the comments below the answers to ask for clarifications. If you improve your question by editing it it appears again on top of the "active question" queue. There is no need to repost identical questions.